# Does random variable $X<\infty$ almost surely imples that $E(X)<\infty \ a.s$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I have the following stupid question in my mind while i am studying for exams.
Does $X<\infty \ a.s$, implies that $\mathbb E(X)<\infty$?

Further on this, is the converse of the above statement true? Do give me a bit summary on this. Thanks very much.

I thought this was true until I realize the following example: Let's consider a simple symmetric random walk, we know that each state is null-recurrent. Let $\tau_L$ be a stopping time when the walk first hits $L$ started from $0$. then 
$$\mathbb P(\tau_L<\infty)=1$$
so $\tau_L<\infty \ a.s.$
but we also know that 
$$\mathbb E(\tau_L)=\infty$$
Is this a counter-example? Thanks, i am a bit weak on measure theory.

Comment: Perhaps an easier counterexample.  We know that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and so $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{6}{\pi^2n^2} = 1$.  Consider then a discrete random variable who takes value $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ with probability $\frac{6}{\pi^2 n^2}$.  The expected value of this however would have been a multiple of the harmonic series which we know to diverge.

Comment: so only the converse is true?

Comment: What does $\mathbb E[X]<\infty $ a.s. means ? Notice that $\mathbb E[X]$ is deterministic (it's a constant if you prefer). So, there is no randomness here.

Comment: @surb you are right, i need to drop a.s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)=([0,1], \mathcal B([0,1]), m)$ where $m$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Consider $X(\omega )=\frac{1}{\omega }$.

Then, $X(\omega )<\infty $ a.s. but $\mathbb E[X]=\infty $.

Comment: Very good clear and easy (+1)

Comment: so the $P(X=\infty)=m(\{0\})=0$, while the the area is infinity? it is indeed a simple example.

Comment: Yes exactly. But in probability, it's not a very good idea to interpret the expectation as an area...@KennethNye

Answer (score 2):

An even simpler counterexample is to take $P(X=n)=C/n^2$ where n is a positive integer and $C$ is a normalizing constant.

However, the converse is true. Usually, the expectation is only defined when $X$ is absolutely integrable. We have $P(|X|>M)M\leq E(|X|)<\infty$ for any $M>0$. If $X$ is infinite with positive probability, then $P(|X|>M)\ge P(|X|=\infty)>0$ for any $M$, so the left hand side of the inequality diverges as $M\to\infty$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest counter example I can think of a random variable $X$ which can take values $\{1, 2, 4, ...\}$ where $P(X=n)=\frac{1}{2^n}$ if $n$ is a power of $2$ and $0$ otherwise.. Then

$E(X)=\sum\frac{2^{n-1}}{2^{n}}=\infty $